# Foundation cracks in new home construction North Texas

Tags: foundation, construction, cracks

I am currently building a house in north Frisco and I noticed a some cracks from the middle of the foundation and they go down to the side as see in the pictures. I have not yet contacted the builder as I am trying to get more info on the issue to be able to respond. Are these common and should I be alarmed? I had scheduled a private inspector for the pre sheetrock inspection and I may have to schedule an inspection for this as well. Thank you all in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other pictures: https://ibb.co/8dwsDwz
https://ibb.co/qCv2Lfs
https://ibb.co/7KjZKmb
https://ibb.co/pdF63vf
https://ibb.co/KLj8vrB
https://ibb.co/X2nTgjR
https://ibb.co/SxDJCXV
https://ibb.co/9HQLRh3

Answer (score 1):

I would be concerned with the through thickness cracks ; at least have an independent inspector look at it. My son had a KB  home ( cable tension slab) in Round Rock , the cracks did not show up for a couple years but then no one would write a mortgage on the home. He was able to find a buyer that did not need a mortgage.

Answer (score 1):

Concrete is not designed to crack. When it does, it’s a mistake. The designer and/or contractor does not know the difference between reinforcing steel and temperature steel.

Get it fixed or withhold payment to the contractor until it’s fixed or a structural engineer (not a civil engineer) signs off as “The crack will not get wider.”